# What kind of form does a child born in the UK need to gain citizenship from Algerian parents who do not have ILR?

Tags: united-kingdom

Before 1 January 1983, every person born in the UK was automatically British. The British Nationality Act of 1981, which came into effect on 1 January 1983, stated that a person born in the UK after that date would only be a British citizen if either of the parents was a British citizen or was settled in the UK.

A child born in the UK who is not a British citizen is subject to immigration control. The parents of such a child will normally regularise the child’s immigration status, for example, by applying to the Home Office to have the child given the same leave to remain as themselves. This means that if the child leaves the UK with its parents, for example, for a holiday, re-entry will be allowed within the child’s existing leave to remain.

However, there will be instances when a child leaves the UK without leave to remain having been authorised and therefore requires an entry clearance to return. In these circumstances, the ECO should be satisfied that the applicant meets the conditions set out in paragraph 305.

Immigration Rules paragraphs 304 & 305

Maintenance and accommodation requirements do not apply to a person who qualifies under these provisions.

The visa endorsement must be in line with that of the parent(s) in the UK so the ECO will need to see evidence of this. If the parents have different leave durations, it will be for the longer period.

See ECB13 Endorsements

If the parent is a British citizen (for example, having settled and subsequently registered), the ECO should consider whether the issue of a Certificate of Entitlement or British Passport might be appropriate.

A child to whom this section of the Rules applies may also seek entry under another part of the Rules (for example, as a visitor or student).

Comment: There is no such form for British citizenship where neither parent has ILR.

Comment: I don't feel competent to make this an answer, but other people agreed that this is the [right place to start](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/pbs-dependant-child). And yes, @user16259 is correct. The chlid is not eligible for British citizenship.

Comment: @nina, do you just need a residence permit for the child, and not citizenship?

Comment: What are the details of the situation you are asking about? The description here seems to just be copy-and-paste of rules from some website and not actually your question.

Comment: How old is the child now, and what is the current status of the child's parents in the UK?

Comment: i just want to know if he can get resident permit or citizenship or entry clearance anything he can gain please help me

Comment: if he can't get anything tell if he can join his aunt who lives in uk but without adopting him and also without any company of parents for at least 5 years so he can get citizenship

Answer (score 1):

@nina the child is in Algeria now, with his parents, but he has an aunt in the UK and you would like him to live with her so he could become a citizen of the UK?

There is no way to do that.

If he were to go to school and university in the UK he might eventually get citizenship as an adult but it would take many years and cost at least £20,000 per year in education fees and living expenses.